# DataGrid's column width (width = "*") is not "refreshed"

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid

I got the following code, it consists of a DataGrid that lists items, corressponding to a selected item in a ListBox. Everything works, but the width of the DataGrid Columns acts wierd. I set the width for the "name" column to star, so that the "wert" column takes the space its contents needs, and the "name" column takes the rest. This is working, but with a little problem. When the application starts, all columns are at their minimal width, and only selecting another item in the ListBox updates the width of the columns to the desired values (star for "name", auto for "wert").
I tried using the UpdateLayout method of the datagrid on application load, but that did not help.

Also, i am using an expander, and when all expanders are closed, i have to first expand one of the items, and then load another item in the listbox for the widths to be correct.

Could anyone please point me in the right direction ? :)

**UPDATE:** initial question solved, but there is another little problem:
The columns are not collapsed anymore, but theye are not at their desired size either. They are sized to fit their headers name, not the rows content. This only occurs when the expander is closed by default. When i set the expander to be expanded, all columns are set to their contents width, as desired.

Here is the used code :

```
<Grid.DataContext>
            <XmlDataProvider x:Name="XmlData" Source="entries.xml" XPath="Root/Person" />
</Grid.DataContext>

<ListBox Name="PersonListBox"
                ItemsSource="{Binding}"
                ItemTemplate="{StaticResource listBoxTemplate}"
                IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
                Visibility="Visible" SelectionMode="Single"  SelectedIndex="-1" DataContext="{Binding}">
            </ListBox>

<DataGrid IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" Name="itemGrid"
                 DataContext="{Binding ElementName=PersonListBox, Path=SelectedItem}" 
                 CanUserResizeColumns="False"
                 CanUserResizeRows="False"
                 IsReadOnly="true"
                 Background="White"
                 HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
                 AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                <DataGrid.Resources>
                    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="items" Source="{Binding XPath=item}">
                        <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
                            <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="@name"/> 
                        </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
                    </CollectionViewSource>
                </DataGrid.Resources>
                <DataGrid.ItemsSource>
                    <Binding Source="{StaticResource items}"/>
                </DataGrid.ItemsSource>
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Header="Name" Binding="{Binding XPath=@name}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Wert" Binding="{Binding XPath=@value, Converter={StaticResource sumConverter}}}"/>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGrid.GroupStyle>
                   <GroupStyle>
                    <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                                        <Expander >
                                            <Expander.Header>
                                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
                                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Items, Converter={StaticResource sumConverter}}" />
                                                </StackPanel>
                                            </Expander.Header>
                                            <ItemsPresenter />
                                        </Expander>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Style>
                    </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                </GroupStyle>
                </DataGrid.GroupStyle>
            </DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I found this [post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/wpf/thread/ce7ec7b1-2b48-4392-b57b-584081fa32f1) that led me to the answer.  In summary the default `GroupStyle.Panel` (StackPanel) cannot fit the DataGrid Width "*" so the columns collapse.  Simply add

```
<GroupStyle.Panel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <DataGridRowsPresenter/>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>               
</GroupStyle.Panel>
```

to your `GroupStyle` and you should be good.

Comment: Have you tried setting the width of the columns to "Auto" instead of "*"?

Comment: Ok so the best solution I've come up with is this:  You can take off the individual `Column.Width` for each column and set the `DataGrid.ColumnWidth` to either "*", "SizeToCells", "SizeToHeader", or "Auto".  Because you have the `IsExpanded` set to `false` the Columns will not know what the size of the contents until they're expanded.  Perhaps have them expanded initially and close them on load?

Comment: Thanks for your help so far, but i dont like having them opened initially. I think i'll add a "expanded" event to the expander, which then checks the maximum width of the current CollectionViewGroup grouping and sets the column to that width. The group should be accessible through the expanders DataContext. I hope that will work, 'cause it would mean i'm starting to understand it ^^. Thanks for the help, much appreciated :)

Comment: i cant find a good way to measure string width for this....so i tried setting the columns width to star (auto) like in xaml when the expander expands. This works, but again not instantly: the first time i expand nothing happens, then when i expand a 2nd time the columns resize correctly. There has to be an easy way to do this ?? I mean i have data grouped by expanders, and i want columns to fit the content of that data (except for first row, it should be star-widthed). The Grid does not "see" the data yet, but y doesnt it work when i set the columns width again when expanded event gets shot ??